# How to access <tag> by its id attribute and not array position?

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

I would like to understand how to access a `<tag>` by its id and not through array position. Example:

```
<someNameHere id="hello">
 <home>
 </home>
 <home>
 </home>
</someNameHere>
<someNameHere id="hi">
 <home>
 </home>
 <home>
 </home>
</someNameHere>
```

I don't want to do this:

```
$myXML->someNameHere[1]->home[0]
```

I want to go access someNameHere by its ID "hi".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) for that.

```
$nodes = $myXML->xpath('//*[@id="hi"]');

if (!empty($nodes))
{
    $someNameHere = $nodes[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

Can you show one example, on adding a child to it ? Or is simple a mether of doing $someNameHere->addchild(yeah) ?